# Form #after_build is not working for PHP 7x

Tags: 7, forms

I'm using #after_build in one of my custom module form like follows

```
  $form['profile_image'] = array (
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
     '#after_build' => array("change_pic"),
  );
```

and the function is

```
function change_pic($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  if($form_state['values']['profile_image']['fid'] != 0){
    // my code goes here..
    return $element;
  }
}
```

It's working fine in PHP 5x version. but throws the following error in PHP 7x version.

> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function change_pic(), 2 passed
>   How can we handle this in PHP 7?

Any inputs would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 2 args to an after build method, the element and the form state.

Just remove the extra one and it’ll work:

```
function change_pic($element, &$form_state)
```

Answer (score 0):

Clive's answer to use only those 2 arguments is correct; but this is also wrong on your code:

```
 $form['profile_image'] = array (
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
     '#after_build' => array("change_pic"),
  );
```

this will wipe out any other after builds added by other modules. You should add like this:

```
 $form['profile_image']['#after_build'][] = 'change_pic';
```